# Can I override the default C# string to decimal converter?

Tags: c#, wpf, string, decimal, converters

In my WPF program there are many input fields for users to specify amounts. For sake of user ease, I've been asked to modify the field so that if a user types in 10K, the value updates to 10,000 once the user moves on to the next field.

There are few other short cut options:

- t,T,k,K ==> Thousand
- m,M ==> Millions
- b,B ==> Billion

If there was only one field, It would have been pretty easy to change it but since there are many fields across multiple screens, I'm looking for a simple solution that would be able to automatically parse the user input.

So it is possible to override the default string to decimal converter?

Or can I change the default `IFormatProvider` for string to decimal conversion?

Comment: Nah.  You should use an IValueConverter for this, if you're MVVMing and using Bindings.  If not, then user input has to be interpreted and copied to the actual storage area for the value.

Comment: And what input field you use, regular TextBox?

Comment: I can use IValueConverter...  I'm just hoping to avoid fixing all my regular TextBoxes with it.   If the override cannot be done, this is my fallback plan.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this example. The example is from here http://putridparrot.com/blog/typeconverters-and-xaml/

```
public class AbbreviatedNumberConverter : TypeConverter
    {
       public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
       {
          return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
       }

       public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
       {
          return destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor) || 
                     base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
       }

       public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
                                CultureInfo culture, object value)
       {
          string text = value as string;
          if (text == null)
          {
             return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
          }

          if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
          {
             return 0.0;
          }

          if (culture == null)
          {
             culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
          }

          double number;
          if (AbbreviatedNumeric.ValidateDouble(text, out number, culture))
             return number;

          return 0.0;
       }

       public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
                         CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
       {
          if (destinationType != null && value is Double)
          {
             if (destinationType == typeof(string))
             {
                return value.ToString();
         }
          }
          return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
       }
    }

    public Double Amount
    {
       get { return (Double)GetValue(AmountProperty); }
       set { SetValue(AmountProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AmountProperty =
                        DependencyProperty.Register("Amount", typeof(Double), 
                        typeof(OnlineStatusControl), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));


    [TypeConverter(typeof(AbbreviatedNumberConverter))]
    public Double Amount
    {
       get { return (Double)GetValue(AmountProperty); }
       set { SetValue(AmountProperty, value); }
    }

    public static class AbbreviatedNumeric
    {
       public static bool ValidateDouble(string value, out double? numeric, 
                  CultureInfo cultureInfo = null)
       {
          double result;
          if(ValidateDouble(value, out result, cultureInfo))
          {
             numeric = result;
             return true;
          }
          numeric = null;
          return false;
       }

       public static bool ValidateDouble(string value, out double numeric, 
                  CultureInfo cultureInfo = null)
       {    
          if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
          {
             numeric = 0;
             return false;
          }

          if (Double.TryParse(value, out numeric))
          {
             return true;
          }
          if (value.Length > 0)
          {
             if (cultureInfo == null)
             {
            cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
         }

         NumberFormatInfo numberFormat = cultureInfo.NumberFormat;
         if (value.Substring(0, 1) == numberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator)
         {
            value = "0" + value;
         }
         if (Double.TryParse(value.Substring(0, value.Length - 1), 
                         NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | 
                         NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite |                      
                         NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign |
                 NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | 
                         NumberStyles.AllowThousands | 
                 NumberStyles.AllowExponent, cultureInfo, out numeric))
         {
            switch (Char.ToUpper(value[value.Length - 1]))
            {
                case 'B':
               numeric = numeric * 1000000000;
               break;
            case 'M':
               numeric = numeric * 1000000;
               break;
            case 'K':
               numeric = numeric * 1000;
               break;
            default:
               return false;
            }
                return true;
         }
          }
          return false;
       }
    }
```

You can also do the opposite by simply doing this from the C# code behind

```
static string FormatNumber(int num) {
    if (num >= 100000)
        return FormatNumber(num / 1000) + "K";

    return num.ToString("#,0");
}
```